# Unusual fuel consumption

Tags: fuel-consumption

So I haven’t been driving for a very long time only about a year or so, and my car is an Eagle vision Esi 1994. 
I just replaced my inner and outer tie rods and put oil into the car, I haven’t had any work with rebalancing or rotating tires(which is my next thing to do) but lately my car has been going thru gas a lot faster than it use to and I’m not sure what’s causing it
Also to mention I did replace the spark plugs 5 mmonths ago, all the tires have tread. 
I’m not sure what could be causing it?
Anyone have advice or tips?

Comment: Start a log.  Let us know the EXACT fuel economy.  Fill the tank, check the odometer.  Drive a few miles, fill the tank again.  One other thing... high percent ethanol gasoline doesn't age well in a tank.  You definitely don't want to fill a tank with that stuff and let the car sit for a year.

Comment: Sounds like it is due for a good service - oil& filter, fuel filter, air filter, checking tyre pressures etc and then measure the fuel consumption.

Comment: Okay, I’ll do some more. Checking and change the filters out. Also the oil filter was changed the last time I did an oil change, which its been less than 10,000miles so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not align the wheels after the tie rod replacements, the wheel angles can easily be off quite a bit. If the toe angles are opposing, plenty of resistance will be created. Certainly enough to cause a noticeable increase in gas consumption. It's like pushing a shopping cart with a sticky wheel at the grocery, takes extra muscle.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any more than you've provided. we're just guessing. Have you checked the Overhead Travel Information System (OTIS)? It provides instant fuel usage as well as average fuel consumption. At least find out what the car itself thinks your mileage is.

The 3.3L [averages](https://fueleconomy.gov/feg/bymodel/1994_eagle_vision.shtml) 21 MPG while the 3.5L averages 19 MPG. Assess your mileage against these reported values to get a benchmark. Also, don't forget to check the EGR valve. A valve stuck open, or filled with crud, can affect your mileage.